# How can I replace the scheme as single slash?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, deep-linking

Good day, I have a redirect url works with *com.example.com:/redirect* .

**com.example.com** is my scheme, but the result when i use Linking.createUrl("") is *com.example.com://*. How can I replace the scheme as single slash ?